# Как узнать высоту фрагмента в пикселях?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Для определения всех координат и величин фрагмента я создал отдельный метод в отдельном классе.

```
    public static float[] defineDensity(Activity activity) {

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

        return new float[] {displayMetrics.density,
                displayMetrics.heightPixels,
                displayMetrics.widthPixels,
                dpHeight,
                dpWidth};
    }
```

И получаю в класс отрисовки фрагмента эти величины:

```
    private float[] coordinates = new float[5];

    {
        coordinates = MathHelper.defineDensity(getActivity());
    }
```

Но передаю-то я активити `(getActivity())`, что даёт координаты активити, а не фрагмента. Поэтому, прошу подсказать, что передавать во вспомогательный метод или другое решение, как узнать размеры фрагмента (но лучше подскажите, что передавать).

UPD. Как я понял из документации, размер фрагмента можно узнать в методе `onViewCreated`, который обязательно вызывается после `onCreateView`. Добавил `onViewCreated`:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentHeight = view.getHeight();
        fragmentWidth = view.getWidth();
        Log.d("fragmentHeight", String.valueOf(fragmentHeight));
        Log.d("fragmentWidth", String.valueOf(fragmentWidth));
    }
```

Результат почему-то ноль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как `Fragment` отображается на `View`, к которой он прикрепляется, то размер `Fragment` зависит именно от неё. Назвовём эту `View` - контейнером.

Также у `Fragment` есть собственное `View`, которое Вы задаёте в методе `onCreateView` и добавляете в этот контейнер.

Таким образом на Ваш вопрос есть минимум 2 ответа - Вы хотите узнать размер контейнера (доступный для отображения размер) или размер собственной `View` (реальный отображаемый размер)? Не исключено, что эти два значения одинаковы, если, например, собственная `View` у `Fragment` с параметрами атрибутов `height` и `width` =  `match_parent` или размер содержимого не входит в контейнер.

Что касается методов `getHeight` и `getWidth` у `View`, то они показывают реальный отображаемый размер `View` в пикселях, но только когда `View` прошла метод жизненного цикла `onLayout` и доподлинно определилась со своим размером. Если пытаться определять размер собственного `View` в методе `onCreateView` или `onViewCreated`, то Вы получите значение 0, потому что `View` еще даже не пыталась проходить свой жизненный цикл.

Что касается размера `View` контейнера, то в зависимости от условий, есть вероятность, что он уже был отрисован еще до присоединения к нему `Fragment` (например если это не первый `Fragment`, который через него прошел), а потому в методе `onCreateView` у `Fragment` можно попытаться сделать так:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (container != null) {
        int height = container.getHeight();
        int width = container.getWidth();
        Log.e("TEST", "Parent height = " + height + ", Parent width = " + width);
    }
    ...
}
```

В случае же, если `View` контейнера и `View` самого `Fragment` еще не были прорисованы, то всегда можно отложить запрос размеров на момент после отрисовки всех `View`, например так:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         @Nullable final ViewGroup container, 
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(/*Id*/, container, false);

    ...
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (container != null) {
                Log.e("TEST",
                        "Parent height = " + container.getHeight()
                                + ", Parent width = " + container.getWidth()
                );
            }
            Log.e("TEST",
                    "Fragment View height = " + view.getHeight()
                            + ", Fragment View width = " + view.getWidth()
            );
        }
    });
    ...

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: А можно заранее отрисовать сначала View, а потом уже инициализировать фрагмент? Где это лучше сделать?

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов В принципе нечто подобное возможно под очень специфичный функционал, который врятли будет в том виде, который Вы себе представляете. В любом случае такой подход будет **не**правильным и гораздо сложнее в реализации. Если у Fragment есть собственный `View`, то он должен создаваться именно в методе `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 1):

У фрагмента нет размера, есть размер у `View`, который вписан в `Fragment`

Код, который вы привели вычисляет не размер `Activity`, а размер текущего дисплея. Так что погуглите как найти размер `View`, который инфлейтится в `Fragment.onCreateView()`

Comment: вроде нащупал решение, но не работает. обновил код.

Comment: Такой код не будет работать, в `onViewCreated()` `view.getHeight()` - вернет ноль (потому что `View` еще не получил свой размер) - гуглите дальше :)

Comment: Спасибо, бармалей, за совет гуглить, мне уже ответил ниже и по делу Артилирриум, который всегда даёт правильные и развёрнутые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вычислить высоту фрагмента, можете попробовать так:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                view.getHeight();
            }
        });
    }
});`
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0)