# Android как узнать высоту и ширину дисплея в пикселях

Tags: android

Разрешение моего телефона **2160×1080**, так уверяет не один сайт описывающий характеристики мобильных гаджетов. И такое же разрешение показывает AIDA64 для android.

Пробовал два варианта, оба возвращают **2030x1080**. Как получить верное значение? И куда делись **130px**? Я предполагаю, что это status bar.

Вариант 1:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Вариант 2:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: Вас спасет вот этот метод: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize(android.graphics.Point)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам поможет вторая часть [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666287/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85/666542#666542) про отложенный запрос размеров View.

Смысл в том, что прорисованная `View` должна выдать свои настоящие размеры. Потому запрашивать надо у самой корневой `View`-`ViewGroup`.

А сталкивался я с ситуацией с пропавшей высотой экрана на телефонах, где системные кнопки не хардварные, а софтварные и могут подъезжать снизу. Например на таких телефонах, как Sumsung S8 - S9.

`DisplayMetrics` выдает неверный размер дисплея, потому что от него вычитается размер подъезжающих системных кнопок.
В моём случае, даже когда системные кнопки были скрыты, `DisplayMetrics` всё равно не давал мне настоящий размер дисплея.